# Grunt usemin not generating right paths in HTML

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using Yeoman and grunt, and having problems with running the grunt build task. Everything goes through without errors, but the index.html I'm using us not changing directory paths for the javascript files included in the bottom of the body.

```
    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/stickUp/stickUp.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

Here's my code in Gruntfile.js for reference:

```
    grunt.initConfig({
    // configurable paths
    yeoman: {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    },
    watch: {
        compass: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scss/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/css/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,svg,webp}'
            ]
        }
    },
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            livereload: 35729,
            // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    'test',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                livereload: false
            }
        }
    },
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
                urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
            }
        }
    },
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scss',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false,
            assetCacheBuster: false
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
            }
        },
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },
    // not used since Uglify task does concat,
    // but still available if needed
    /*concat: {
        dist: {}
    },*/
    // not enabled since usemin task does concat and uglify
    // check index.html to edit your build targets
    // enable this task if you prefer defining your build targets here
    /*uglify: {
        dist: {}
    },*/
    'bower-install': {
        app: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
        }
    },
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,webp}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
    },
    usemin: {
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>'],
            basedir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        },
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*.css'],
    },
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    cssmin: {
        // This task is pre-configured if you do not wish to use Usemin
        // blocks for your CSS. By default, the Usemin block from your
        // `index.html` will take care of minification, e.g.
        //
        //     <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
        //
        // dist: {
        //     files: {
        //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //             '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //             '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //         ]
        //     }
        // }
    },
    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                //collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true*/
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                src: '*.html',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },
    // Put files not handled in other tasks here
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    'scripts/{,*/}*.*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },
    modernizr: {
        devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
        ],
        uglify: true
    },
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'compass',
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'compass',
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            //'svgmin',
            'htmlmin'
        ]
    }
});
```

I've been trying different things, but the result is the same. In the dist directory index.html the javascript paths stay the same as in the development directory and the file gives a 404 error.

Anyone that could lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you provide also a task you are running from grunt (`build` task I guess).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are loading the grunt tasks

looks like this-

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify'); -for single tasks

or you can use-

require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); -loads all grunt tasks

if you have load-grunt -tasks in your package.json

Your code is not wrapped by module.exports = function (grunt) { }

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    'use strict';

Your code here

};